# winform ShowDialog(this) still fail

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, showdialog

I am already aware that using ShowDialog() can cause the form to go behind to its parent form. So I look for a solution.

Many says that the solution is to pass the parent form as a parameter to the child form.

Something like this.

```
using(Form f = new Form1())
{
     f.ShowDialog(this);// while the 'this' is the parent form calling
}
```

but this code still fails.
This is the scenario.

> Open the child form showing the dialog, then when the child form window is still active, click show desktop (or press Window+D) then, open other application.
>   after opening the application minimize it or close it. now after you close or minimize the other application.

Now the child form is already behind the parent form. now you should press alt+tab or click it form the taskbar to work it again properly.

I will appreciate for any help.

Comment: Why not use Show instead and set the Dialog to topmost??

Comment: what about `f.ShowDialog();`

Comment: `f.TopMost = true;`?

Comment: no I cant set TopMost to true, because sometimes they are multitasking, either opening a browser or other application

Answer (score 1):

Good question. It seems like then the child dialog is visible, and `Windows+D` is pressed, the parent form ignores the request (or possibly the OS prevents sending a minimize request to the parent form because it has an active modal dialog). Just guessing. The parent form is never sent a minimize message.

You can observe this by using `TOOLS -> Spy++` and notice the lack of window messages sent to the parent window when the child dialog is showing and `Windows+D` is pressed. The messages received are in the orange box:

[image]

That means the parent form is never actually minimized. Windows stops painting it, but opening another window turns the painting back on.

So using the `WM_ACTIVATEAPP` as a reference point, force the parent form to be minimized. This has the side effect that the child dialog is made invisible. Then listen for the `SC_RESTORE` message, and reshow the child dialog:

```
public class RestoreForm : Form {

    private const int SC_RESTORE = 0xF120;
    private const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
    private const int WM_ACTIVATEAPP = 0x1C;

    public RestoreForm() {
        Button btn1 = new Button { Text = "ShowDialog(...)", AutoSize = true };
        btn1.Click += btn1_Click;

        Controls.Add(btn1);
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        if (f2 != null) {
            if (m.Msg == WM_ACTIVATEAPP) {
                if (f2.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized) {
                    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
                }
            }
            else if (m.Msg == WM_SYSCOMMAND) {
                var w = m.WParam.ToInt32();
                if (w == SC_RESTORE) {
                    f2.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                    //f2.Visible = true; // ignores staying on top of previous parent
                    f2.ShowDialog(this);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Form f2 = null;
    void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        f2 = new Form { Text = "Child" };
        f2.ShowDialog(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I just finished reading it. But for some reason I just got lost. Because i dont have any experience using Spy++ and windows message by now. But i will try it.

Comment: @zer09 Everything in windows is sending messages. You can see a bulk of the `WM_` constants here (or on MSDN): http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Constants.WM And `Spy++` is just a tool to listen to those messages (and some other utilities).

Comment: ohh thats a lot, BTW thank you, for now i will try practicing spy++

Comment: +1 Good points, although it's worth mentioning that (since you need to keep a reference to the child form in `f2`), complete code should attach to `f2.FormClosed` and finish closing the form/setting `f2` back to null.

Answer (score 0):

My closest workaround to solve this is set ShowInTaskbar and MinimizeBox to false.

Actually I can just disable ShowInTaskbar without disabling the minimize box, but there is no point, allowing the user to minimize the child form but still they cant perform any action on the parent form.